# Koon-ut-kal-if-fee at odds with Vulcan pacifist philosophy

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, vulcan

Is this a canon inconsistency? In the TOS episode "Amok Time", a slice of Vulcan culture is revealed to us in the form of a ritual combat to the death.
However, Vulcans are typically portrayed as pacifists, seemingly avoiding violent conflict at all costs. Is this an inconsistency in canon, or is it reconciled somewhere?

Comment: I always thought the point (or at least **a** point) of that episode was to show that Vulcans too have an irrational side, and that the pon farr was a way of reconciling this. And btw, I tried to change TNG to TOS, but edits have to be at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 17):

It's reconciled by the fact that Vulcans openly acknowledge (on the rare occasions on which they discuss such matters at all) that Pon Farr (and all it's associated rituals) are irrational, illogical, and generally at odds with their values--but it's an an unavoidable biological urge they have no power to control. From Amok Time:

> SPOCK: The birds and the bees are not Vulcans, Captain. If they were, if **any creature as proudly logical as us were to have their logic ripped from them as this time does to us**. How do Vulcans choose their mates? Haven't you wondered? 
>   
>   
>   KIRK: I guess the rest of us assume that it's done quite logically. 
>   
>   
>   SPOCK: No. No. It is not. **We shield it with ritual and customs shrouded in antiquity.** You humans have no conception. **It strips our minds from us. It brings a madness which rips away our veneer of civilisation.** It is the pon farr. The time of mating.

(Emphasis added)

So yes, you're completely right about there being an inconsistency here. But it's an inconsistency in the Vulcans themselves, brought on by their biology. Every seven years they lose all ability to retain logic, and so they fall back to ancient rituals that help guide them through this difficult time.